# Difference ways to assign variable in java?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

Which ways is the best to assign java variables? And What is the differences? See this;

```
   public class Test {
       private String testString;

       //getter & setter here.

       public void testMethodOne() {
            this.testString = "Hello World!";
       }

        public void testMethodTwo() {
            testString = "Hello World!";
       }

        public void testMethodThree() {
            setTestString("Hello World!");
       }
   }
```

Which is the best,  **this.testString = "xxx"** or **testString = "xxx"** or **setTestString("xxx")**?

Comment: Please Read Item 13-14 from Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.

Comment: I find unnecessary use of `this.` a burden on the eyes, but it's a matter of taste. Calling `setTestString` is unnecessary from inside the class unless you know it has a useful side effect other than just amending the value.

Comment: @AmitDeshpande Neither item 13 or 14 is relevant here.

Comment: btw this wil give a compile error, seriously at runtime it will generate the same byte code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommended you prefix your class attributes with "`this`". This way you would have a better view of member variables vs local variables.
And use getters/setters when you can't access class attributes directly (access them from another class).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @dadu you should use `this` as we are using in helper classes (setter/getter) method.

If you are using any other class not helper class ( without any setter/getter) then, It is always recommended to use with `constructor` .Use a `constructor` and assing variable values.Basically the purpose of the constructor are to initialize the member variable.The constructor example like :-

```
private int intUerId,intUserType,intBranchId;
private String vchUserName,vchFullName,vchPrivilege;

public LoginBean(int intUerId, String vchUserName, String vchFullName,
            String vchPrivilege,int intUserType,int intBranchId) {
        super();
        this.intUerId = intUerId;
        this.vchUserName = vchUserName;
        this.vchFullName = vchFullName;
        this.vchPrivilege = vchPrivilege;
        this.intUserType=intUserType;
        this.intBranchId=intBranchId;
    }
```